# Manually telling my ListBox's scrollbar where to be

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.AutoScrollOffset.Y = 10;
}
```

I'm trying to manually set the location of my vertical scrollbar using code during runtime. This is what I've tried.

The .Y property says: "Gets or sets the Y coordinate of this point". Why doesn't this compile and give me an exception:

> Error 1   Cannot modify the return value
>   of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.AutoScrollOffset'
>   because it is not a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a crucial difference between value types and reference types.  AutoScrollOffset is of type Point, a struct which makes it a value type.  When you use the property getter, you get a *copy* of the value.  Setting the Y property only sets the property on the *copy*.  The C# compiler can recognize this particular usage problem.  But not this one:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var offset = listBox1.AutoScrollOffset;
    offset.Y = 10;     // Compiles, but doesn't work
}
```

To make it work if you have to assign the property with a value of type Point:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(listBox1.AutoScrollOffset.X, 10);
}
```

Which does not actually work to scroll the listbox, it will only affect the position of the control when it is embedded in a scrollable container, like Panel.  Check ScrollControlIntoView for reference.

Assign the TopIndex property instead.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, AutoScrollOffset behaves iteself just like the Location. You cannot change Location's X or Y, but you can set Location to new Point(...).

Answer (score 2):

It is a `struct`, so you need to set a new `Point` into the property instead of accessing `struct` members.

Because `struct` types are immutable, accessing them via a property introduces an oft-unknown quirk of its design.  You call the get of the property by doing `listBox1.AutoScrollOffset`, this gives you a copy.  You then set into the *copy* the new value of Y, not the property itself.  Thus when you go and review the value of the `struct` you thought you were editing, you find it hasn't changed.

As for controlling the scroll, I just found this:

http://moiashvin-tech.blogspot.com/2008/04/scroll-listbox-programmatically.html

Doesn't control it via coordinates, but via the items in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
listBox1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(listBox1.AutoScrollOffset.X, 10);
```

Comment: This doesn't scroll the vertical scrollbar, when it should according to the code I'm reading. Any ideas?

Comment: Here is an MSDN post that discusses this issue : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/6c847d06-49b8-4dad-9b05-1b0f8baabd5a